# Display dialogfragment inside Fragment occupying a portion of the screen?

Tags: android

I have been battling with this for some days now.

#### I have an activity with two fragments A and B.

#### I want to display a dialog fragment inside Fragment B (only).

#### Instead the dialog fragment show in the middle of activity (see picture below).

[image]

#### What I want is below

[image]

Below is a snippet of my code for FragmentB:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {


    //...Some code....

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_order_create_fragment, container, false);


    }





    void showDialog(int position, Product item){
        MyDialogFragment dialogFragment=new MyDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "MY_DIALOG_FRAG");
    }
    

    //...More Code....

}
```

PS: `showDialog(int position, Product item)` is used to show the dilogFragment.

I'm using `getChildFragmentManager()`
But I have also tried `getFragmentManager()`

This the code for MyDialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment  {

    //...Some code....

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(AppCompatDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.CustomDialog);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       
        return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_cart_item_layout, container, false);
    }


    //...More code....
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other fragments, you can attach a DialogFragment to a particular container. For example, if you had a `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"/>` in your Fragment B, you can use

```
void showDialog(int position, Product item) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.container, dialogFragment, "MY_DIALOG_FRAG");
    ft.commit();
}
```